# Adjust plot and box height in a shiny dashboard regardless the Operational System and the Screen Resolution

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to adjust plot and box height in a shiny dashboard regardless the Operational System and the Screen Resolution? Below for example I would like to cover the 80% percent of the screen in height in the dashboard body in any screen that the app will be displayed?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      navbarPage("Navbar!",
                 tabPanel("Plot",
                          boxPlus(
                            plotlyOutput("plot1")
                          )
                 ))
    ),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
      p <- qplot(Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
      p <- ggplotly(p)
      hide_legend(p)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Read the help doc for `plotlyOutput`, the example is given almost verbatim in its *Usage*: `plotlyOutput(outputId, width = "100%", height = "400px", inline = FALSE)`.

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution. This is one does not seems to work. First of all it does not include the boxPlus which remains the same

Comment: Is this question no different from your previous question, then?

Comment: which Q do you mean?

Comment: I use a different method to achieve the same goal in that one.

Comment: What about your question about `input$screenHeight` ? It solves the problem, no ? The boxPlus doesn't adjust to the height of the plot ?

Comment: I had problem to adapt highcharts. In any case I used different methods so I think both are useful. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you want

```
tabPanel("Plot",
         boxPlus(
           plotlyOutput("plot1", height = "80vh"), 
           height = "80vh"
         )
)
```

`80vh` means 80% of the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining `fluidRow` and `column` functions to do this. For a box that takes up 80% of the tabPanel on desktop screens:

```
tabPanel("Plot",
         fluidRow(column(9,
                boxPlus(width=12,
                        plotlyOutput("plot1")
                        )
                 ))
        )
```

Conversely, for a plot that takes up 80% of the box container,

```
tabPanel("Plot",
                boxPlus(width=12,
                        fluidRow(column(9,
                                 plotlyOutput("plot1")
                                 ))
                       )
        )
```

In all cases, because `fluidRow` and `column` use Bootstrap grids, once you get down to a mobile screen size the components will rearrange for mobile view.

Additionally, it seems a little odd that you're combining a navbarPage with a DashboardPage - do you actually want a tabsetPanel or tabItems instead?

Comment: Sorry I meant 80% in height. Or whatever percent. I just want it to be the same in every screen resolution in every browser it will be displayed.